# iCloud photo question

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

I have iCloud Photo Library turned on for all my devices (iPhone, iPad, IPod).

My question: Is there any way to have iCloud turned on but have photos save to just one device with out having them saved to all devices?

If I try to delete the picture or video it deletes from all 3 devices, is there a way to have iCloud Photo Library turned on but still be able to just have pictures on one device?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do this by heading to Settings > iCloud then turn off the Photos option. This will disable photo sharing between devices, allowing you to delete your photos off of one device but keep them on the others, or vice versa. Hope this helps!